# Error in Java Installation: "Stop! `java 13.0.2-open` is already installed"

Tags: java, installation, terminal, sdkman

so I installed java on my macos, then when I installed java (sdk install java 13.0.2-open) on my macos console I experienced an error

`Stop! java 13.0.2-open is already installed.`

even though when I type comments (`java --version`) on the mac console I get an error

`Unable to locate an executable at "/Users/kokoe/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java" (-1)`

These are my results when I type comments (`which java`) in my MacOS console

`/usr/bin/java`

[Screenshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlNSD.png)

Comment: Please copy/paste your error message into the body of the post, instead of using a screenshot.

Comment: i was copy paste my eror on my question

Comment: this is my eror , about java instalation : 
Stop! java 13.0.2-open is already installed.